# Swipe Indication for user Android

Tags: android, user-interface, swipe

Suppose I have a `ListView` displaying exactly 10 rows that is not intended to scroll.

When the user swipes, the next list of 10 rows would be displayed.  The bottom of the `ListView` would say something like "page 2 of 3".

How can I indicate to users that they should swipe to get the next page?

Comment: Why limit the `ListView` to X items only instead of a single list of everything? Sounds confusing to have multiple lists to navigate

Comment: I agree, look at the sdk samples for tips on how to handle slow adapters if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are best off rolling your own solution using a `ScrollView` and/or a `ViewPager`

According to a GoogleIO presentation about ListViews, they are coded with many "behind-the-scenes" tricks in order to optimize performance.

When you start trying to modify how they work, then you end up with a complex widget that doesn't make use of its own complexity and optimizations.

Some type of vertical view pager could be good for what you see though.

Reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 1):

A page indicator might be helpful like you said. I view-pager may be another option. In that case I would use: http://viewpagerindicator.com/